# Recursion on an array of objects containing nested array of object to return an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, recursion

I have been provided with an array of objects containing questions and subquestions **if it exists**. The subquestion can have a nested array of the object which again can have a nested array of objects and so on.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
 let survey = [
     {question: 'some question 1'},
     { 
       question: 'some question 2', 
       subQues: [{ question: 'some question 3' }] 
     },
     { 
      question: 'some question 4', 
      subQues: [
       { question: 'some question 5', 
        subQues: [ 
          { question: 'some question 6', 
            subQues: [{ question: 'some question 7' }] 
          } 
        ] 
      } 
     ] 
   },
  {question: 'some question 8'}
]
```

The expected output should be an array consisting of all the question inside the subquestion

**Output ->** `a = ['some question 1','some question 2','some question 3','some question 4','some question 5','some question 6','some question 7','some question 8']`

I need to solve this problem **recursively** as it is unknown how many times nesting can occur.
I tried this problem using recursion like this **->**

**My Solution**

```
function recursion(surveyData) {
  let a = []
  for(let i = 0; i < surveyData.length; i++) {
    if(surveyData[i].subQues) {
      a.push({question: surveyData[i].question})
      recursion(surveyData[i].subQues)
    }
    else {
      a.push({question: surveyData[i].question})
    }
  }
  return a
}
```

In spite of the fact that I'm not getting an error, the result is not what I'm expecting

**My Output**

['some question 1','some question 2','some question 4','some question 8',]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you had named your `quest` values differently it would be easy to see where your problem is, which is that you are not doing anything with the result of calling `recursion` inside itself. You probably want `a = a.concat(recursion(surveyData[i].subQues))`

Comment: Thanks for the remark and pointing the issue on the question.

Comment: It should be simpler with a straightforward recursion.  `const extractQuestions = survey => survey .flatMap (({question, subQues = []}) => [question, ...extractQuestions (subQues)])`